# Check to see if function call has correct argument types

Tags: javascript, types, constructor, arguments, eval

Is there a way to check whether a function call has the correct argument types.
Let's say I have a function called changeCar which takes two arguments one of type Car and another of type String.

```
function Car(){
this.make="generic";
}

function changeCar(car,mytype){
car.make=mytype;
}

var mycar=new Car();
changeCar(mycar,"ferrari");
```

Is there anyway to tell whether mycar and "ferrari" are the correct types needed to run changeCar?
I need to do this before the script is run if possible maybe using eval or try/catch to look for mistakes.

The application allows students to type in a javascript scripts and looks for errors in the function arguments and function calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeCar (car, mytype) {
    if ( car instanceof Car && mytype.toLowerCase ) {
        car.make = mytype;
    }
}
```

[Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) FTW.

Comment: Is there an advantage of checking for _toLowerCase_ over doing a check like `String(mytype) === mytype` ? (Note absence of `new`)

Comment: He's trying to check the code for errors, not check if the function params are correct. He wants to 'compile' and get 'compile-time errors'. Therefore, this isn't the answer.